# Sorting of Array of Objects not working with Array.sort() method

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, methods

I am attempting to sort an array of objects by a name property that exists on each object. When using the `sort()` method with the code below I am getting the following error:

`ERROR ReferenceError: b is not defined`

Here is my code:

```
myArray.sort( (a, b) => {
return (typeof a.name: string === 'string') - (typeof b.name === 'string')|| a.name - b.name || a.name.localeCompare(b.name)};
```

Here is what is odd though...

When I run:

```
myArray.sort( (a, b) => {
console.log(a.name);
console.log(b.name);
```

It logs the names perfectly fine. What am I missing??

**Just to be a thorough little bit of context:**

I am using this method after doing an HTTP call from an angular service.ts file and this array is being passed to my component and subscribed to. And I am using Angular, so this would be Typescript compiling to JavaScript. I also have another `myArray.forEach()` method just below my `sort()` method and that is working.

Comment: please add the array as well.

Comment: The subtraction operator doesn't work on string values; what is it that you expect that expression to do?

Comment: Doesn't look like valid typescript syntax to me.

Comment: @NinaScholz How does the array (or its content) change the `ReferenceError`?

Comment: With that many `||` operators, you would be best to add parentheses throughout, but really, you might want to go back to using something easier to *debug* using good old-fashioned `if .. else`

Comment: Okay. So what I am attempting to do is sort an array of objects by each object's name property. THEN I want to use a `forEach()` method to push them to different respective arrays. The `forEach()` method is working. But the `sort()` method is not. So it is definitely something in my `sort()` method I am missing or some syntactical error. `ReferenceError: b is not defined` is very puzzling though. Especially when I can log the same argument with `console.log(b.name)` and it works.

Comment: Please add a [minimal, **complete and verifiable** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) which shows the actual problem.

Comment: what is that doing `typeof a.name: string === 'string'`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```js
var a = [
  { name: "John" },
  { name: "Jack" },
  { name: "Bob" }
];

a.sort(function (a, b) {
  if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
  if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
  return 0;
});

console.log(a);
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you! I am new to TypeScript and working out some of the kinks. Maybe I should maybe just stick to writing JS for my projects

Comment: @newman As you wish, I guess you know that TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript, hence you can use JS when you are not sure how to do it with TS :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a comparison which works independently of the type of string or number, by moving numerical values to top.

```js
var array = [{ name: 20 }, { name: 21 }, { name: 2 }, { name: 11 }, { name: 1 }, { name: 'John' }, { name: 'Jane' }, { name: 'Frank' }, { name: 'Mary' },] 

array.sort((a, b) => (typeof a.name === 'string') - (typeof b.name === 'string') || a.name > b.name || -(a.name < b.name));

console.log(array);
```